# How to get a response "stream" from an action in MVC3/Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3, .NET4, C#.

I need to create some XHTML using a Razor View. I do this via an Action.

```
    public ActionResult RenderDoc(int ReportId)
    {
        //A new document is created.

        return View();
    }
```

I then need to take the output from this and convert it to a Word Doc. I am using a 3rd party component to do this and it expects a "stream" or a "file" for the XHTML source that is read in for conversion to a DOC, like the following:

```
document.Open(MyXhtmlStream,FormatType.Html,XHTMLValidationType.Transitional);
```

**My Question:**

What would be a good way to call the "RenderDoc" Action and obtain the result as a stream to feed into "MyXhtmlStream".

Many thanks.

**EDIT: I have had another idea !!!**

1) Render the View within the action to create a String(XHTMLString). I have seen a method to do this on SO.

2) Create a MemoryStream and put this string into it.

```
Stream MyStream = New MemoryStream("XHTMLString and encoding method");
```

**EDIT2: Based on Darin's answer**

I need to clasyify a little further, and I hope to do this via tweaking Darin's code for my purpose.

```
 public class XmlDocumentResult : ActionResult
 {
  private readonly string strXhtmlDocument;
  public XmlDocumentResult(string strXhtmlDocument)
  {
    this.strXhtmlDocument = strXhtmlDocument;
  }

  public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
  {
    WordDocument myWordDocument = new WordDocument();
    var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
    response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    myWordDocument.Open(response.OutputStream, FormatType.Html, XHTMLValidationType.Transitional);
  }
 }
```

The above is closer to what I need. Note the 3rd Party WordDocument type. So there is still the issue of how I get the "strXhtmlDocument" into the "Response.OutputStream?

Comment: you really can't get it from the action. thats too early in the pipeline.

Comment: When you say //A new document is created do you have a stream at that point? Or are you retrieving this document from somewhere?

Comment: I have no stream. Basically I have just used a Razor View, via the "RenderDoc" Action, to create the XHTML. I then want to convert this into a DOC. Logically I had hoped to just incorporate a call to this action into the open method, but it is not as simple as this.

Comment: Are you creating the document from what is on the screen or from something the user is uploading?

Comment: I am creating the document from stored data, so the Razor view is rendering this data as an XHTML and then this is converted to Word. I have just had another idea. See EDIT.

Comment: Rob, I have lost your answer??

Comment: Rob, wanted to award you points for your help so marked up the comments above although your stuff seems to have disappeared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just write a custom ActionResult to handle that:

```
public class XmlDocumentResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly Document document;
    public XmlDocumentResult(Document document)
    {
        this.document = document;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        document.Open(response.OutputStream, FormatType.Html, XHTMLValidationType.Transitional);
    }
}
```

You could of course adjust the response `Content-Type` if necessary and also append a `Content-Disposition` header if you want.

And then simply have my controller action return this custom action result:

```
public ActionResult RenderDoc(int reportId)
{
    Document document = repository.GetDocument(reportId);
    return new XmlDocumentResult(document);
}
```

Now the controller action doesn't need to handle plumbing code anymore. The controller action does what a typical controller action is supposed to do:

1. Query the Model
2. Pass this model to an ActionResult

In your case the model is this `Document` class or whatever it is called.

Comment: Hi Darin, Thanks for this. Very comprehensive. One point I would add to this is that I am passing the ReportId to the View and with this it is pulling together all the report ingredients. So Return View() literally does return my rendered XHTML. I cannot see in your example where the Razor bit comes in.

Comment: Yes, I need to replace "Document document = repository.GetDocument(reportId);" with a call to another Action which calls the Razor View which creates my XHTML, or create a string inline via a direct call to the Razor Engine.... which I have seen solutios for on SO.

Comment: I have added an Edit which hopefully clarifies. I still have the issue of how I get "strXhtmlDocument" into the "Response.OutputStream, unless I am missing something? Hugely appreciate the great help. Thanks.