# Redirecting to URLs - asp.net vs MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My question is somewhat similar to 
[How to get a response "stream" from an action in MVC3/Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104984/hot-to-get-a-response-stream-from-an-action-in-mvc3-razor)

but I've tried their approaches with no success.

**DETAILS**

Im using MVC3, .net4, c#,

javascript and a 3rd party component to open files.

I have a `viewStuff.js` connected to a `ViewFile.aspx`.

in my `viewStuff.js` I have

`var component = 'code to initialize'`

***PREVIOUSLY***

I used to have `aspx` pages connected to this javascript and they worked perfectly

in my `viewStuff.js` i had

`component.openFile("http://localhost:8080/ViewFile.aspx");`

which redirected to the aspx page

`ViewFile.aspx.cs` file returned data related to the file in the form of a `HTTPResponse`

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Response.Clear();

            string stuff = "abcd";
            this.Response.Write(stuff);

            this.Response.End();
        }
```

***NOW***

All I want to do is replace this `aspx` with a `Controller` that will return the same thing.

in my `viewStuff.js` i have

`component.openFile("http://localhost:8080/ViewFile/Index");`

the `Controller` looks like

```
public class ViewFileController: Controller{

   public ActionResult Index()
   {
     string stuff = "abcd";
     return stuff;
   }
}
```

My only problem is that my component.openFile() method is unable to get to the   `Controller` using the MVC URL. 
 I've got active breakpoints as soon as `Index()` starts but they never 
 get hit.

I dont know if its
   - the URL
   - MVC - the fact that URLs are methods and not physical files

Also, i'm unsure of how to mess around the the RouteConfig() if that could help.

EDIT: route config:-

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }                    
            );
```

(I can get more details if needed. Let me know before downvoting)

Comment: Do you want the viewstuff.js to return data to the page or are you trying to redirect to another page.  Not sure i undersand your problem but you may need to use a JSONResult method rather than an ActionResult

Comment: Can you show you routing configuration?

Comment: What happens if you run the app and then past `http://localhost:8080/ViewFile/Index` into the browser address bar? Does the breakpoint get hit then? Also, you may want to try `return Content(stuff);` in your controller method.

Comment: Yes, the breakpoints get hit using any browser. thats why i was thinking maybe my 3rd party component doesnt like mvc style url's

Answer (score 2):

2 possibilities come to mind

1. Return a `ContentResult` from your controller action:

   ```
   public class ViewFileController : Controller
   {
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
          string stuff = "abcd";
          return Content(stuff);
      }
   }
   ```
2. Use a view:

   ```
   public class ViewFileController : Controller
   {
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
          return View();
      }
   }
   ```

   and in the corresponding Index.cshtml view you could put whatever markup you want.

Also before putting any breakpoints in your controller open the `http://localhost:8080/ViewFile/Index` url in your browser address bar and see if it returns the correct and expected data.

Comment: Yes, the breakpoints get hit using any browser. thats why i was thinking maybe my 3rd party component doesnt like mvc style url's, i return expected data as my 'PREVIOUS' section highlights

Comment: `ContentResult` didn't help. Is there any way to get to a view before hitting the controller?

Comment: No, this is against the whole concept of the MVC pattern where Views are rendered by Controller actions. So by the very definition, the entry point of an MVC application is the Controller.

Comment: Is there anything i can do to make my URL like a .aspx URL?
I've tried returning the bytes of the `stuff` string as a `File` as well as a `FileStream`, no effect.

Comment: Why are you using ASP.NET MVC if you want to continue with classic WebForms concepts such as accessing some .aspx pages directly?